# How can I hide <div> in an HTML page in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have one div as the following:

```
<div>
  <% # IIF(DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem,"Specifiction2").ToString()<> "","")
<div>
```

I want to hide the above div when "spcefication2" is blank on a .aspx page.

How can I do it?

Comment: You can use a similar logic to choose whether to put style="display:none" attribute on the div

Comment: sorry can u write code to show how I write that code

Comment: *"Specifiction2"*? *"spcefication2"*? Do you mean *"Specification2"*? It contributed two more words to [my list](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.

1. You are using IIF, but IIF should never be used. Always use IF instead. The only reason to use IIF is you are stuck with a pre-2008 compiler, and even then, you should use something else.
2. The easiest way to do what you are describing is via an id and runat="server", you can then either set the visible property (which will mean that the div never gets emitted) or set the style to display:none
3. If you want to do it inline, per your example, the code is

   ```xml
       <div style="display:
           <%#    IF(string.isnullorwhitespace(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Specifiction2").ToString), "none", "block") %>">
       </div>
   ```
4. You are using Eval and container.dataitem, you should look into using ItemType For your grid/repeats, then referencing the value as item.Specification
5. The above would be much easier if you declared a function in your code behind, taking a string and returning the string none/block.